import sqlite3 python Flask
I want to perform the operation in the code that I wrote below in the app.py file in Python Flask, in the file named Doktor.py in the file named Package.
@app.route("/gdoktor", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gdoktor():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        doktor_id = request.form['doktor_id']
        doktor_sifre = request.form['doktor_sifre']
        conn = sqlite3.connect('hospital.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT doktor_id,doktor_sifre FROM Doktorlar WHERE doktor_id=? and doktor_sifre=?", (doktor_id,doktor_sifre))
        doktor = c.fetchone()
        if doktor is None:
            print("Sorry")
        else:
            return render_template("home.html")
    return render_template("gdoktor.html")

Can you give me a small example of how I can do this? I would be very happy if you could guide me.

you can write a function, which take 2 parameter, doktor_id, doktor_sifre  and then write logic inside it and return output accordingly

I don't understand the question.  It seems that you already have code that does what you want, so what is the problem?

You are doing
@app.route("/gdoktor", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gdoktor():
(...)
        if doktor is None:
            print("Sorry")
        else:
            return render_template("home.html")

Observe that effects of prints are not visible in browser of user. You should return either valid Response (what render_template does) or at least text (it will not be pretty, but at least visible to user), which might be done by replacing
print("Sorry")

using
return "Sorry"

